# The attribute 'translate' is not allowed in Magento 2.2

Tags: checkout, layout, magento2.2

I was created simple custom module in magento 2.1. And it's working fine in magento 2.1.9.

But today I tried to installe in magento 2.2 and it's shows this error:

> 1 exception(s): Exception #0
>   (Magento\Framework\Config\Dom\ValidationException): Element 'item',
>   attribute 'translate': The attribute 'translate' is not allowed. Line:
>   1920
>
> Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Config\Dom\ValidationException):
>   Element 'item', attribute 'translate': The attribute 'translate' is
>   not allowed. Line: 1920

Here is file where generate this error

```
<referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
    <arguments>
        ...
        ...
            <item name="fee" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component"  xsi:type="string">Vendor_Module/js/view/checkout/cart/totals/myfile</item>
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="title" xsi:type="helper" translate="true" helper="Vendor\Module\Helper\Data::getCustomText"/>
                </item>
            </item>
        ...
        ...                    
    </arguments>
</referenceBlock>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not allowed to use `translate` attributes for `<item>` nodes that have `xsi:type` anything else other than `string`.
Just remove `translate="true"` from this line

```
<item name="title" xsi:type="helper" translate="true" helper="Vendor\Module\Helper\Data::getCustomText"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for replay. It's working if I remove translate="true". But it's working translation in multilanguage?

Comment: you should include the translation in your helper class.  So this line of xml just returns the result of `Vendor\Module\Helper\Data::getCustomText`. use `__('Text here')` inside your `getCustomText` method and the text will be translated without the need of the `translate` tag,